# How to insert a firebase server timestamp using the iOS SDK in Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the ["Offline Capabilities" section of the iOS guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-latency) it mentions `kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp`, which doesn't seem to work in a Swift project (auto complete doesn't prompt it).

I tried `[".sv": "timestamp"]` as the Swift example did. But it complains that this can not be set with other values and has to be the only value for at the given path.

I tried:

```
ref.childByAutoId().setValue(["text": "foobar", ".sv": "timestamp"], withCompletionBlock: {...}
```

And it gave me the error that ".sv" can't be saved with other value.

What I wanted to do is to save the createdAt timestamp along with other values for the object. And I'd prefer to use the server time to avoid client clock skew.

How can I do that?

Comment: can you try setting only the .sv value and using {} instead of []? Or maybe put it in self appointed variable instead of .sv?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the `".sv":"timestamp"` between brackets `[ ]` when you add it to your `Firebase` entry.

eg:

```
let objectToSave: Dictionary <String: AnyObject> = ["date": [".sv": "timestamp"], "key1": "value1", "key2": 1234.....]
```

[Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88RGF.png)

It should be written to your Firebase as:

```
date: 1463329843759
```

[Firebase screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAZHP.png)

Comment: where is this referenced in the documentation?

Comment: Thanks - this is phenomenally useful - they should add it back in

Comment: This does not work it just adds a string [".sv": "timestamp"] to the document

Comment: NSGodMode, this is from 2016... when Firebase wasn't even acquired by Google, and Swift was at version 2 at most

Answer (score 7):

As of Firebase 4.0 you can use ServerValue.timestamp()

for example:

```
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("userExample")
    let values = ["firstName": "Joe", "lastName": "Bloggs", "timestamp": ServerValue.timestamp()] as [String : Any]

    ref.updateChildValues(values) { (err, ref) in

        if let err = err {
            print("failed to upload user data", err)
            return
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's the ServerValue class I cannot find it. is it in Firebase framework?